# Copy listview1 selected items to listview2

Tags: vb.net

I have code which successfully copies the first row from one listview to another.

```
Listview2.Items.Add(Listview1.Items(0).Clone())
```

However, it does not copy selected items (unless there is only one selected item and it happens to be the first item). What am I missing?

Comment: `Listview1.Items(0)` will always be the first element of the list... either use `SelectedIndices` or `SelectedItems` properties to get the ones you have selected

Comment: how? can you edit my code? :)

Comment: @VAN I somewhat re-wrote your question, if my edit does not accurately represent what you wanted to ask, please edit it further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the selected items of ListView1 with [`ListView1.SelectedItems`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.selecteditems(v=vs.110).aspx).

I see that you have used .Clone() to create a new entity to add to ListView2 - the [`ListViewItem.Clone()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listviewitem.clone(v=vs.110).aspx) function creates an object, so you need to cast it to a ListViewItem to be able to add it to another ListView.

Iterating over the selected items, we get...

```
For Each si As ListViewItem In ListView1.SelectedItems
    ListView2.Items.Add(DirectCast(si.Clone(), ListViewItem))
Next
```

N.B. You should use [`Option Strict On`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zcd4xwzs.aspx) to make sure that all variable types match up - that option will let Visual Studio tell you where something is awry, and even give some useful suggestions as to how to correct it.

Comment: what happened was it didn't transfer or clone any selected items in the second listview although there was no error whatsoever

Comment: i just fixed it. it seems i had to put your code on the first line of my private sub which is weird.

Comment: @VAN Glad to hear you got it working. Without knowing the other code in your sub, I can't comment on what might have been the problem, but if there is no problem now then there is no need to go into that and I guess we are all happy :)