# Not working when copy items from ListView1 to ListView2. (vb)

Tags: vb.net

I have 2 different forms and 2 different listview where form 1 showing all the order and I want to copy the listview items into second form for checkout purpose. For now, the code is running fine (no error), my form 1 can show the list but my form 2 doesn't show anything.

First form: (cart1) with ListView1 
Second form: (OrderDetails) with ListView2

*my listview1 having 5 columns

What is the problem in my code? I had tried to make all of them as public sub but still not working as well.

Here my code:

```
 For Each cartlist As ListViewItem In Cart1.ListView1.Items

     ListView2.Items.Add(DirectCast(cartlist.Clone(), ListViewItem))

 Next
```

Thank you.

I refer from here: 
(Copy listview1 selected items to listview2)
[Copy listview1 selected items to listview2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42493103/copy-listview1-selected-items-to-listview2)

Comment: If you have your ListView in `Details` view (or you want to): `For Each header As ColumnHeader In Cart1.ListView1.Columns Me.ListView2.Columns.Add(DirectCast(header.Clone(), ColumnHeader)) Next`. Otherwise it won't show anything (but it should show the Items in `List` mode).